# drush rsync among sites

Tags: drush

I have the following alias group set in the setA.aliases.drushrc.php:

```
  $aliases[‘site1'] = array(
      'root' => '/var/www/site1',
      'uri' => '88.88.88.11/site1',
      'remote-host' => '88.88.88.11'
  );

  $aliases[‘site2’] = array(
      'root' => '/var/www/site2',
      'uri' => ‘88.88.88.22/site2',
      'remote-host' => '88.88.88.22'
  );

  $aliases[‘site3’] = array(
      'root' => '/var/www/site3',
      'uri' => ‘88.88.88.33/site3',
      'remote-host' => '88.88.88.33'
  );
```

Now, I have updated @site1, and would like to sync with other sites in setA alias group, can I just use the following command "drush rsync @site1 @setA"?

Or how can I exclude @site1 from destination @setA as it is actually the source?

Answer (score 0):

In Drush 6 and earlier, the rsync command did make some attempt to operate on site alias lists; however, we recently decided that this feature was not useful enough to continue to maintain it, so we removed it from Drush 7.  Truthfully, I'm not even sure that it's working right in Drush 6 -- casual tests showed inconsistent results.

Therefore, the best way to do this would be to just call `drush rsync` once for every destination site.  You could do this with a simple script.

```
#!bin/bash
for site in $(drush sa @setA --format=csv --fields=name)
do 
    if [ "$site" != "site1" ]
    then 
        drush --yes rsync @site1 "@$site"
    fi 
done
```

Comment: That would be a bad news to me.  Is there any way I can do it by batch as I have many similar sites. Call `drush rsyn` once for every destination site would be time consuming and easy to miss a site.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, don't forget to click to accept it. Welcome to the group!